# FInd object in array by value and update entire object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a list of objects and sometimes I receive an update from the API for one of those objects and what I need to do is to find the object with the id of the one to update and update the entire object...

I was trying to avoid a for loop because the list could be very very long.

So what I was trying to use is $.grep but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
// item is the response data from the API
var item = res.item;
var index = $.grep(arrayOfItems, function (e, i) {
  if (e.id === item.id) {
    return i;
  }
});
arrayOfItems[index] = item;
```

the item is not updated unfortunately...

Comment: Please share sample object structure

Comment: $.grep won't use the return as value, it only filters the existing array elements and the return boolen is used to include/exclude that element in the resultant

Comment: Also if this is going to occur often on large data there are libraries you can use to manage the merges

Comment: Hmmm... You really should overthink this "I don't want to use a for loop but a external lib function." How do you think they are going to loop through this array? Just because it's encapsulated in another function doesn't mean there is suddenly voodoo available ;) To understand what I mean go to http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js press "ctrl + f" and type in "grep". Now you are able to see the function (and the containing for loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.map and $.grep return both an array so you will never get the index.

> Inside $.map or $.grep function you need to return true or false based
>   on your filter logic. They re not useful in your case.

if your structure is not ordered you can only loop trough it and stop the loop when you find your element... like that:

```
var item = res.item;
var index = "";
$.each(arrayOfItems, function(i,v){
    if(item.id == v.id){
        index = i;
        return true;
    }
});
arrayOfItems[index] = item;
```

if you wanna order your structure before loop use this:

```
arrayOfItems.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return a.id > b.id;
});
```

i ve made a fiddle with an example https://jsfiddle.net/L08rk0u3/

Answer (score 2):

If it's speed you're after, especially with a long list, you may consider indexing your list by id when you first retrieve it, making updates later quicker than having to loop the entire array to find an index.

To demonstrate, assume you have retrieved an array of objects

```
var data = [
    {id:1,data:'hello'},
    {id:2,data:'world'},
    {id:3,data:'foo'},
    {id:4,data:'bar'}];
```

now create an object which represents your data where the property is the Id (object properties cannot start with a number, so if `id` is numeric, prefix it) and the value is the index back into the original array. So, the above data would be transformed to

```
var dataIndex = {
   id1:0,
   id2:1,
   id3:2,
   id4:3
};
```

This can be done trivially with a function

```
function indexDataById(data)
{
    var index = {};
    $.each(data, function(e,i){
        index['id' + e.id] = i;
    });
    return index;
}

var dataIndex = indexDataById(data);
```

Now, when it comes to your update, you can find the index instantly using the id

```
var updateId = 2;
var elementIdx = dataIndex ['id' + updateId];
data[elementIdx] = myNewData;
```

The one complication is that you need to go back and update the index if the `id` of the new data has changed:

```
var updateId = 2;
var elementIdx = dataIndex [`id` + updateId];
data[elementIdx] = myNewData;
delete dataIndex[elementIdx]
dataIndex['id' + myNewData.id] = elementIdx;
```

This should be easy enough to handle atomically with your update.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) method like this.

**Code snippets:**

```
// item is the response data from the API
var item = res.item;
var index = $.map(arrayOfItems, function (e, i) {  
  if (e.id === item.id) {
    return i;  
  }
});
if(index.length)
  arrayOfItems[index[0]] = item;
```

**Update:**

```
arrayOfItems[index] = item;
```

This will work if `index` array has an single element. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okqz9ewk/1/)

But,

```
arrayOfItems[index[0]] = item;
```

This is the appropriate way since it is an array.

Comment: This would work, as long as you changed it to `arrayOfItems[index[0]]` - as `map` does return array, but also filters out elements if you return `undefined` or `null` as you've implicitly done by not returning outside of the `if`

Answer (score 0):

try this way using **$.grep**

```
var arrList = [
               {name :11,id :11},{name :12,id :12},{name :111,id :111},
               {name :13,id :13},{name :15,id :15},{name :11,id :11},
               {name :41,id :41},{name :31,id :31},{name :81,id :81},
               {name :91,id :91},{name :13,id :13},{name :17,id :17},
               {name :1111,id :1111}
              ]

console.log(arrList);

var respItem  ={name :1111000,id:1111};
var intSearchedIndex;

 $.grep(arrList,function(oneItem,index){

  if(respItem.id==oneItem.id){
    return intSearchedIndex = index;
  }

})    

arrList[intSearchedIndex] =respItem; 
console.log(intSearchedIndex,arrList);
```